# vscode debugging xUnit test - ignoring envFile from launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, vscode-debugger, xunit.net

I'm writing some tests with xUnit in visual studio code.

Tests extract some sensitive data from Environment.

I'm storing those variables in .env file, in the workspace root folder.

If I load that file content in my shell and then issue `dotnet test`, tests runs correctly and use sensitive data extracted from environment.

In order to debug those tests, I'm setting `envFile` parameter in `launch.json` like this:

[image]

This usually works in a console application, but not when I debug a test through the VSCode Debug button:

[image]

The content of my .env file (in the workspace root, next to .csproj) is:

```
TEST_VAR=aaaa
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

Thanks.

Update:

In the end I changed approach. If you are interested in a different (and more powerful) solution, I described it [in this article](https://dev.to/andreav/using-dotnet-iconfiguration-inside-xunit-projects-4o6b)